# Is it a good strategy for the Seer to reveal his identity at the beginning?

Tags: werewolf

Should Seer take part in the Sheriff contest and indicate his identity at the beginning?

When I watched a so-called top werewolf boardgame live, this Seer publishes his identity at beginning, he argues with the werewolf who act as Seer with the aim of misleading the villagers to vote someone his claimed as "werewolf". I though this Seer will soon die, but werewolves do not dare to kill him at first two round. Interesting. Killing hims means accepting the fact that he is real Seer.

I though Seer should keep secret and survive as long as he can, so that to investigate more players. This is a way to keep him safe and time to get more information.

Is it a good strategy for the Seer to reveal his identity at the beginning?

Comment: Is this about One Night or about Werewolf? The strategies are very different in each game.

Comment: This is pretty clearly about werewolf, not one-night-werewolf; removing the one-night tag

Answer (score 8):

It is almost never wise to claim to be the seer. And it seldom happens. But sometimes it can be a smart move. Especially if another player claims to be the seer. 
If two people claim to be the seer, it is almost certain that one isn't. And that is most probably a wolf. The true seer can check this. And start a discussion. There are three possibilities:

1. The true seer fails to convince and is killed by the vilagers. Next day, the fake seer will almost certainly be killed.
2. The false seer is killed by the vilagers. Next night, the real seer will almost certainly be killed.
3. The vilagers decide not to kill any of those. In that case, if the wolves are killing the real Seer, the fake seer will almost certainly killed by the vilagers.

All three cases link the death of the seer with the death of a wolf. And that is not a bad ratio. Yes you lost the seer. But he took a wolf too.

But beware, sometimes a mean game master can add two seers to the party. And that can become a bloodbath.

Comment: Some roles, like Village Idiot, require that player to try to get lynched by the village. This can add another voice to the debate of who's the Seer (or other special roles that could possibly identify Wolves like the Little Girl).

Comment: I would add in a small paragraph on bodyguard and witch. Especially with the bodyguard in play, the werewolds should not dare to attack the seer in the very first night after revealing, because he will most certainly be protected.

Also, it depends on the number of werewolfs. If it is 2-3 and you can already identify one, its not that bad to reveal.

Answer (score 1):

Questions about werewolf strategy often depend on the *meta* of the group, which is the set of expectations and play-styles that tend to accumulate around particular play groups. It also depends on whether the moderator adjusts the game based on that meta.

For example, if the current meta in your group is "Seer always reveals first day", then that might result in "Werewolves kill the revealed Seer first night". But then maybe in one game the wolves *don't* kill the revealed Seer, and use that to discredit her to trick town into lynching her. So in later games the Seer might only reveal if on the chopping block or if she has successfully found a wolf.

Or maybe the Doctor always protects the Seer, which makes it difficult for the wolves to do anything about her, so one of them fake-claims Seer in the hopes of drawing the Doctor's protection and creating confusion. So then in the next game, the moderator might adjust the Seer role to prevent claiming, or might put in two Seers to sow confusion, or she might make it so that the Seer only gets to investigate on even-numbered nights.